# Ajax event within dataTable which is re-rendered by another ajax event does not execute

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I am building an invoice application. When the user selects the client, then the services associated with the client are re-rendered in a dataTable by an ajax event. But, the ajax event of the selectOneMenu in the dataTable does not fire.

This is the form which lets the user select a client:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="clientSelect" value="#{invoiceBean.client}">
        <f:ajax execute="clientSelect" listener="#{invoiceServiceListener.processClientValueChange}" render=":test :invoiceData"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{invoiceBean.clientOptions}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

This will fire an ajax event which fills the services array in the invoiceBean and re-renders the dataTable which displays the services in another selectOneMenu in the dataTable. This part works properly.

This is the datatable that is re-rendered after selecting the client by the above form:

```
<h:panelGroup id="test">
    <h:dataTable id="invoiceData" value="#{attributes.priceAttributes}" var="loop">
        <h:column>
            <ui:param name="service" value="service#{loop}" /> 
            <ui:param name="description" value="description#{loop}" />
            <ui:param name="price" value="price#{loop}" />
            <h:form id="invoiceSelectMenu">
                <h:selectOneMenu id="selectMenu" value="#{invoiceBean[service]}">
                    <f:ajax event="change" execute="selectMenu" listener="#{invoiceServiceListener.procesServiceValueChange}" render="@form" />
                    <f:attribute name="row" value="#{loop}" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{invoiceBean.services}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
                <h:inputText id="description" value="#{invoiceBean[description]}" />
                <h:inputText id="price" value="#{invoiceBean[price]}" />
                <h:outputText value="#{loop}" />
            </h:form>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>  
</h:panelGroup>
```

The selectOneMenu is filled properly. However, the ajax event in this select one menu does not work after it has been re-rendered by the first form. But, if I manually fill the services array without submitting the first form, then this ajax event executes normally. By the way, this ajax event also sets a value to the description and price input fields, which should be re-rendered when the event happens. The invoiceBean is request scoped.

Comment: Why didn't you read the message formatting rules in the editor's help before replacing all `<` and `>` by `[` and `]`?

Comment: If you have event handlers on DOM elements and replace those with AJAX content, the events are no longer attached. Is that the issue here?

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not well acquainted with this DOM terminology. Can you elaborate, please? How can i fix the issue? If you have a link regarding this matter, please share it. I'm fine reading about it myself, I just couldnt find a helpfull link when i searched in on google. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the code formatting. But the question was in general pretty hard to understand. I've reindented the code, removed all noise (unrelated tags/attributes) from the code and rewrote the question in better understandable English. Please review if this is indeed what you're actually asking.

Comment: Yes. That's my question Mr. Balus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be tricky. Due to [JSF spec issue 790](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-790), whenever you re-render some content containing *another* `<h:form>` using `<f:ajax>`, then its view state will get lost. To solve this, you'd basically need to reference the full client ID of *another* `<h:form>` inside `<f:ajax>` instead of some containing component. But you've basically multiple forms inside a `<h:dataTable>` which can't be referenced by an absolute client ID.

You'd need to rearrange the code to put the `<h:form>` outside the `<h:dataTable>` and change the `<f:ajax>` to `execute` only the necessary components.

```
<h:form id="invoiceDataForm">
    <h:dataTable id="invoiceData" value="#{attributes.priceAttributes}" var="loop">
        <h:column>
            <ui:param name="service" value="service#{loop}" /> 
            <ui:param name="description" value="description#{loop}" />
            <ui:param name="price" value="price#{loop}" />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="selectMenu" value="#{invoiceBean[service]}">
                <f:ajax execute="selectMenu,description,price" listener="#{invoiceServiceListener.procesServiceValueChange}" render="@form" />
                <f:attribute name="row" value="#{loop}" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{invoiceBean.services}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:inputText id="description" value="#{invoiceBean[description]}" />
            <h:inputText id="price" value="#{invoiceBean[price]}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{loop}" />
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>
```

and then reference it form the first form as follows:

```
<f:ajax execute="clientSelect" listener="#{invoiceServiceListener.processClientValueChange}" render=":invoiceDataForm" />
```

Note that some component libraries such as PrimeFaces have already workarounded/solved this in the component library specific ajax engine. So if it might happen that you're already using PrimeFaces, you could also replace `<f:ajax>` of the first form by `<p:ajax>`.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `<f:attribute name="row" value="#{loop}" />` may not do what you expect it does. It will set `null` because `<f:xxx>` tags run during view build time, not during view render time tag. The `#{loop}` is not available during view build time. But that's subject for a different question :)

Comment: Thank you Mr. BalusC. If you happen to read this, what tag should i use instead of <f:attribute> to send param to the ajax event? If the question has already been asked, and if you have a link, I could read it myself.

Comment: Hey i got another problem, related to this one. When i change the render to "description price" it doesn't work anymore. It only works with @form, why?